# Tkinter, How to make an array entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I want to add an entry widget in my tkinter window but i don't want a string var but an array with this shape: ([1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]). Because I want to multiply the return value with an array.
How can I do this ?
Thank you

```
value=([1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1])
entree = Entry(Mafenetre, textvariable=value, width=30)
entree.pack()
b = Button(Mafenetre, text="OK", command=ok)
b.pack()
def ok():
   v=entree.get()
   newarray=array*v
```

Comment: how do you want to do that? what should the entry box show? where/how are you going to update the 1s? can this question be any more unclear?

Comment: I tried to make my question more clear. Sorry about that. If it's not clear enough don't hesitate to tell it

Comment: I don't know which kind of inputs you're going to receive but tkinter doesn't have a "ArrayVar" all the possible variables are BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar. You can use the string var and convert the value to an array after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do what you want. You can only enter strings in the entry widget. You will have to write code to convert the string to an array.